How to install this package with `pip -e`?
I want to install this package, which is part of the openEMS project, in "development mode" so that I can change the code and see what happens. I have always done this by doing pip install -e path/to/package. For this one, however, this does not work:
$ pip install --user -e .
DEPRECATION: Loading egg at /home/myself/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openEMS-0.0.36-py3.12-linux-x86_64.egg is deprecated. pip 24.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use pip for package installation.. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12330
Obtaining file:///home/myself/opt/openEMS-Project/CSXCAD/python
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 132, in get_requires_for_build_editable
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zcbdct2_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 464, in get_requires_for_build_editable
          return self.get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zcbdct2_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 332, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zcbdct2_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 302, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zcbdct2_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 503, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zcbdct2_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 318, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

It looks like it does not find Cython, however:
$ pip list | grep Cython
DEPRECATION: Loading egg at /home/myself/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openEMS-0.0.36-py3.12-linux-x86_64.egg is deprecated. pip 24.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use pip for package installation.. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12330
Cython             3.0.11

and if I do python and then import cython, it works fine.
If I do python setup.py install --user then it is installed and I can use it, but to test changes I have to uninstall it and install it again every time.
How can I either install it with pip -e or achieve the same goal using python setup.py?

pip install -e is equvalent to python setup.py develop. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/development_mode.html#legacy-behavior

@phd If I install like this it works the same as install in this case.

Modern pip uses build isolation, in your case it uses a transient virtual env /tmp/pip-build-env-zcbdct2_/. For packages that don't require build dependencies or packages that declare build dependencies in pyproject.toml it's not a problem. But your package is quite old, requires Cython and doesn't provide pyproject.toml. You can try to disable build isolation using --no-build-isolation. The full command should be
pip install --user --no-build-isolation -e .


Thanks, but it fails also, with error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'.

@user171780 pip install wheel Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D++error%3A+invalid+command+bdist_wheel
